# Leaving kivy app when pressing 'escape'

Tags: python, kivy, keyboard-events

I'm using keyboard events following this example:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    player1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    player2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PongGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'w':
            self.player1.center_y += 10
        elif keycode[1] == 's':
            self.player1.center_y -= 10
        elif keycode[1] == 'up':
            self.player2.center_y += 10
        elif keycode[1] == 'down':
            self.player2.center_y -= 10
        return True
```

Source:
[How do you check for keyboard events with kivy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280341/how-do-you-check-for-keyboard-events-with-kivy)

But sometimes when I press `esc`, the app is left even I didn't order the app to do it. Is there a built-in method of Kivy that makes the app shut down when pressing `esc`? Is there a way to disable it?

LOG that appears in shell:

> [INFO              ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...

EDIT: The keyboard event listener is disabling when I change screen using Screen Manager (`kivy.uix.screenmanager`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an automatic behaviour of kivy. You can turn it off by setting the exit_on_escape config token to 0, as described at http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.config.html .

Comment: nice! You answered the question, I'll check it. But what about the event listener? Do I have to reactivate it every time I change screens?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the event listener. I access the keyboard by binding to `Window.on_key_down` etc., which should be unaffected by this kind of thing.

Comment: Yes, this binding! If I don't call `self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)` `self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)` every time I change screen, the app doesn't identify the key pressing anymore.

Answer (score 8):

Based on [@inclement answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27590253/4486804),

```py
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'exit_on_escape', '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this message after asking selenium to wait for an ID and then trying to click it.
What fixed it for me was adding a little delay:

```
time.sleep(3)
```