# Identify Ctrl+Click event in a Kivy application

Tags: kivy

I am writing a Kivy application where I want to select a Region Of Interest (ROI) on a scatter image widget. I want to identify when the user presses CTRL+Left Click and then draw a rectangle over the image. Is it possible from within the on_touch_down callback to identify that the user is holding the CTRL button?

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: I think you need to bind to Window.on_key_down and Window.on_key_up and maintain your own set of currently pressed keys. I think the window implementations keep a limited list internally but don't expose it.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280341/how-do-you-check-for-keyboard-events-with-kivy?rq=1). I am wondering if there is a simpler more straight forward way to do this,

Comment: Combine the events `on_key_down`, `on_key_up` with `on_mouse_move` to calculate the diagonal of your rectangle. You can then draw it, and perform other actions following `on_touch_up`.

Comment: I noticed that the Window actually has a `modifiers` property that in principle should contain this.