# How to trigger a key event in Kivy framework?

Tags: keyboard, event-handling, kivy, eventtrigger, kivy-language

For a project i need to trigger a key down event (in this case ESC key) when another event occurs (for example a "y" key press).

A similar behavior can be found in JQuery with the `.trigger()` handler http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Is this possible in Kivy?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check for keyboard events with kivy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280341/how-do-you-check-for-keyboard-events-with-kivy)

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr trigger event != bind event. Please check the link before post an answer.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, but if you want to trigger an event and with that another event(that you bind to a specific keyboard key) with calling a function that presses that key, why don't you just make a function, put your logic there and call that function on two key bindings? Seems like a totally weird way how to use events in kivy. Anyway, [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/core/window/__init__.py) is behind it, so you're welcome to try it the hard way.

Comment: Why should be a weird feature? Practically almost all UI frameworks that i know have this component. It is very useful to reuse the code without filling the code of unnecessary functions. I think this should be useful in Kivy too. It is for reusability, nothing special.