# python: kivy app not closing

Tags: python, user-interface, raspberry-pi, kivy

my kivy simple hello world app is not closing I'm using raspberry pi B and I can't close it I must unplug my raspberry pi 5v adapter to close it

I'm using rasbian jessie
this is the very simple code

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class mamdouh(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='mamdouh')

if __name__=='__main__':
    mamdouh().run()
```

Comment: I think the idea is that you should have some ui element that when clicked will call the `stop` method of your application object. What you could do is assign your app to an actual variable e.g. `app = mamdouh()` then `app.run()`. Then add a `Button`, which will be assigned a function when clicked. In that function call `app.close()` and ti will quit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was trying to say in the comment was. That you need to have some action to cause the quit, as the `run` method will run in a loop indefinitely otherwise.

If you now click on the `Button` labeled '**paul**' it will quit.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class mamdouh(App):

    def build(self):
        lbl = Label(text='paul')
        btn = Button(text='mamdouh')
        btn.bind(on_press=lambda b: app.stop())

        lbl.add_widget(btn)

        return lbl

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = mamdouh()
    app.run()
```

I know nothing about kivy but I can see that this should allow you to quit, whether you want a `Button` in your app is another question.

Another way to kill it and avoid the reboot is simply to go back to the prompt where you launched your app and do <kbd>CTRL + C</kbd>. This will only work from the prompt though, not from the app window itself.

Comment: no the application is opened in full screen and I tried all the keyboard to close it but it don't closed

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280341/how-do-you-check-for-keyboard-events-with-kivy) post shows you how to receive keyboard events. If you click on the button with text **paul**, my example should quit.

Comment: it works but there is a small problem , which is that after I click the button it don't exit , but when I press alt+F4 it exits but why it don't exit directly

Comment: @mamdouhabdelfatah ah ok. How do you launch the application?

Comment: from python2.7 ide i press f5

Comment: Nothing but a rotating circle of the mouse happens