# Python/Kivy : How to call function on ctrl+a keyboard events

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am using `python-2.7` and `kivy-1.9.0`.When i run test.py then shows `Menu1`,`Menu2` Menu.
When i click on `Menu1` Then shows `+Add Menu1` Text . When i click on `+Add Menu1` then call function `root.add_menu1()` . How to make it using `ctrl+a` keyboard key event instead of mouse click ?
Same if i click on `Menu2` then shows `+Add Menu2` Text.After that i press `ctrl+a` key then should be call `root.add_menu2()`function .

## test.py

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.9.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, ObjectProperty,NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.maximize()


class MENU1(BoxLayout):

    def add_menu1(self):
        pass


class MENU2(BoxLayout):

    def add_menu2(self):
        pass

class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    test1_or_test2 = ObjectProperty()
    def display_menu1(self):
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.menu1 = MENU1()
        self.test1_or_test2.add_widget(self.menu1)

    def display_menu2(self):
        self.remove_widgets()
        self.menu2 = MENU2()
        self.test1_or_test2.add_widget(self.menu2)

    def remove_widgets(self):
        self.test1_or_test2.clear_widgets()

class Test(App):
    title = "test"

    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<MENU1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            size_hint: .06, .03
            text: "+Add Menu1"
            on_press: root.add_menu1()


        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y:None
            height: 25
            cols: 5

        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text:""

<MENU2>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            size_hint: .06, .03
            text: "+Add Menu2"
            on_press: root.add_menu2()


        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y:None
            height: 25
            cols: 5

        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text:""

<MenuButton@Button>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    size : (80,30)
    size_hint : (None, None)
    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
    background_normal: ''
    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
    border: (0, 10, 0, 0)


<MainMenu>:
    test1_or_test2: test1_or_test2

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            size_hint_y: 1

            MenuButton:
                id: btn
                text: 'Menu1'
                size : (60,30)
                on_release: root.display_menu1()

            MenuButton:
                id: btn
                text: 'Menu2'
                size : (60,30)
                on_release: root.display_menu2()



        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

                Color:
                    rgb: (1,1,1)

            Label:
                size_hint_x: 45

        BoxLayout:
            id: test1_or_test2
            size_hint_y: 10

        Label:
            size_hint_y: 1
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280341/how-do-you-check-for-keyboard-events-with-kivy it might help !

Comment: @fins thanks for help.Its working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Combined both methods *display_menu1* and *display_menu2* to a common method, *display_menu*.
2. Renamed both methods *add_menu1* and *add_menu2* to *add_menu*.
3. Added a new *ObjectProperty*, *menu* to hook up to either *Menu1* or *Menu2*.
4. Using a *key down binding*, check for *ctrl+a* to invoke *add_menu*.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.maximize()


class MENU1(BoxLayout):

    def add_menu(self):
        print("MENU1.add_menu")


class MENU2(BoxLayout):

    def add_menu(self):
        print("MENU2.add_menu")


class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    test1_or_test2 = ObjectProperty(None)
    menu = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if len(modifiers) > 0 and modifiers[0] == 'ctrl' and text == 'a':  # Ctrl+a
            print("\nThe key", keycode, "have been pressed")
            print(" - text is %r" % text)
            print(" - modifiers are %r" % modifiers)
            self.menu.add_menu()

    def display_menu(self, instance):
        self.remove_widgets()
        if instance.text == 'Menu1':
            self.menu = MENU1()
        elif instance.text == 'Menu2':
            self.menu = MENU2()
        self.test1_or_test2.add_widget(self.menu)

    def remove_widgets(self):
        self.test1_or_test2.clear_widgets()


class Test(App):
    title = "test"

    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MENU1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            size_hint: .06, .03
            text: "+Add Menu1"
            on_press: root.add_menu()


        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y:None
            height: 25
            cols: 5

        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text:""

<MENU2>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Button:
            size_hint: .06, .03
            text: "+Add Menu2"
            on_press: root.add_menu()


        GridLayout:
            size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y:None
            height: 25
            cols: 5

        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text:""

<MenuButton@Button>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5
    size : (80,30)
    size_hint : (None, None)
    background_color: 90 , 90, 90, 90
    background_normal: ''
    color: 0, 0.517, 0.705, 1
    border: (0, 10, 0, 0)


<MainMenu>:
    test1_or_test2: test1_or_test2

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            size_hint_y: 1

            MenuButton:
                id: btn
                text: 'Menu1'
                size : (60,30)
                on_release: root.display_menu(self)

            MenuButton:
                id: btn
                text: 'Menu2'
                size : (60,30)
                on_release: root.display_menu(self)

        BoxLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

                Color:
                    rgb: (1,1,1)

            Label:
                size_hint_x: 45

        BoxLayout:
            id: test1_or_test2
            size_hint_y: 10

        Label:
            size_hint_y: 1
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Ctrl+a @ Menu1]
[image: Img03 - Ctrl+a @ Menu2]