# Python/Kivy : Form submit using enter key

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am moving from one `TextInput` to another `TextInput` using `enter` key.
I want to move from last `TextInput` to `Button` using `enter` key .When I press again enter key then should be call `root.abc()` function.
Can someone tell me how to done it?

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (300, 100)

class User(Screen):

    def abc(self):
        print('Test')

class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
User:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        TextInput:
            id:test1
            focus : True
            text: ' '
            width: 100
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: test2.focus = True

        TextInput:
            id:test2
            text: ' '
            width: 100
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: test3.focus = True

        Button:
            id:test3
            text: 'Ok'
            on_press : root.abc()
```

Comment: Why do you want to call it from the last input? Why not the current Input? Is it necessary to use the input? The Input handles the keyboard event by default, supersaturating a key is a sign of a bad design, it has another bunch of keys at hand, why do not you use them?

Comment: What thing do you want to move? Keep in mind that we are not in your head, be specific and clear.

Comment: @eyllanesc Actually i was confused that how to `focus` button so i thought it would be done from last `TextInput`

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry for inconvenience.I want to `focus` Button from last TextInput using `enter` key after again press enter then function root.abc() should b call.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280341/how-do-you-check-for-keyboard-events-with-kivy might help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we are using a key down binding, check for button's focus and Enter key pressed.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (300, 100)


class User(Screen):
    test3 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if self.test3.focus and keycode == 40:  # 40 - Enter key pressed
            self.abc()

    def abc(self):
        print('Test')


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

User:
    test3: test3
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        TextInput:
            id:test1
            focus : True
            text: ' '
            width: 100
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: test2.focus = True

        TextInput:
            id:test2
            text: ' '
            width: 100
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate:
                test3.background_normal = ''
                test3.background_color = [0, 0, 1, 0.5]    # 50% translucent blue
                test3.focus = True

        Button:
            id:test3
            text: 'Ok'
            focus: False
            on_press : root.abc()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - test1-TextInput]
[image: Img03 - test2-TextInput]
[image: Img04 - Pressed Enter-OK Button]

Comment: Do you know where I could find keycodes for other keys like backspace, space, etc.? I am finding different mappings, eg. enter=13 and so on elsewhere which isn't working