# Keyboard events with kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to create an app where the user can type some text in a TextInput, and press a button to register the data.
Is it possible to bind the Enter key, so the user can just press it inside the Text Input and it calls the register function?

Comment: [This isn't an identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49727988/python-kivy-form-submit-using-enter-key), but you may find it useful for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a single line TextInput you can you can set the `TextInput.multiline` property to `False` then the Enter key emits a `TextInput.on_text_validate()` event. For example:

```
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world')

def on_enter(instance, value):
    print('User pressed enter in', instance)

textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world', multiline=False)
textinput.bind(on_text_validate=on_enter)
```

This is in [Kivy's TextInput documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#usage-example).