# Changing button color from outside of root class

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Im new to kivy, and i encountered problem that i cant find solution to myself. Basically i want to change color of the button everytime i press F4.
This is my code in main loop:

```
if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(F4) or F4s == True:
        F4sw = not F4sw
        if F4sw == True:
            ApexDash().recoilon()
        else:
            ApexDash().recoiloff()
```

And this is the method im referencing to when F4sw is True:

```
class ApexDash(Screen,FloatLayout):

def recoilon(self):
    global F4s
    F4s = True

    print('check')

    self.ids.recoil_on.color = (1,0,0,1)
    self.ids.recoil_off.color = (0,1,0,1)
```

So the issue here is, whenever i press F4 the print check goes through as its supposed to, but the button desnt change color. They do change colors however whenever i call the function from .kv file.

```
Button:
        id: recoil_on
        background_normal: ''
        text: 'ON'
        on_press: root.recoilon()
        color: 0,1,0,1
        size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":0.03, "top":0.65}
```

But when executing the method from outside the class all the widget properties dont seem to work. Sorry if i missed something obvious, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `ApexDash()` creates a new instance of `ApexDash` so every time you call `ApexDash().recoilon()` you create a new layout that is not displayed anywhere (you'd have to call `add_widget` to place it somewhere), change its widgets and then silently discard it. You should store a reference to your actual visible widget to manipulate it, something like:

```
if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(F4) or F4s == True:
        F4sw = not F4sw
        if F4sw == True:
            self.apex_dash.recoilon()
        else:
            self.apex_dash.recoiloff()
```

or

```
if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(F4) or F4s == True:
        F4sw = not F4sw
        if F4sw == True:
            self.ids.apex_dash.recoilon()
        else:
            self.ids.apex_dash.recoiloff()
```

I don't think you should use calls of `win32api` outside of the framework, Kivy can capture keyboard events itself (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280341/how-do-you-check-for-keyboard-events-with-kivy)).

Also try avoiding using `global` in python code. A root widget level property might be a better choice.